# How to solve a Definite Integral (calculus 2)

Tags: calculus

I've begun to learn about these types of questions, however I still have a hard time knowing how to solve them and doing the actual computation. These three integrals are examples of the questions I am experiencing difficulty with.

Any help will be extremely appreciated.

$$\int_{-\surd 2}^{-2}\frac{\operatorname d y}{y\sqrt{y^2-1\;}}$$

$$\int_{-\sqrt{3}/3}^0 \frac{\operatorname d z}{1+z^2}$$

$$\int_{1/2}^{-\sqrt{2\;} / 2} \frac{\operatorname d x}{\sqrt{1-x^2\;}}$$

Comment: Use the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus. Together with the Fundamental Rule of Calculus Student: know your classic derivatives and antiderivatives.

Comment: You'll need a trig substitution for the first one (unless you've dealt with hyperbolic functions); the second involved the arctangent function; the third, the arcsine function.  As **Taladris** says, particularly for exam problems, you _will_ be expected to know some basic anti-derivatives.

Comment: I haven't actually learned any Trig Identities yet, I was given this today, I suspect maybe I will be taught this next class.

Answer (score 1):

For the first one, use the substitution $\;t\colon=\color{red}-\sqrt{y^2-1}$ (the minus sign is related to the bounds).

You should have learnt the other two (arcsine and arctangent).

Answer (score 1):

(1) $$\int_{-\sqrt 2}^{-2} \frac{\operatorname d y}{y\sqrt{y^2-1}}$$

Substitute $s^2 = y^2-1$ and $s\operatorname d s = y\operatorname d y$.

$$\int_{1}^{\sqrt 3}\frac{s\operatorname d s}{y\cdot y\sqrt{s^2}}$$

$$\int_{1}^{\sqrt 3}\frac{\operatorname d s}{s^2+1}$$

Use $\dfrac{\operatorname d \arctan s}{\operatorname d s} = \dfrac{1}{s^2+1}$

$$\Big[\arctan s\Big]_{s=1}^{s=\sqrt 3}$$

$$\arctan \sqrt 3 - \arctan 1$$

$$\frac{\pi}{12}$$

Answer (score 0):

$(1)$ Let $$\displaystyle I = \int_{-\sqrt{2}}^{-2}\frac{1}{y\sqrt{y^2-1}}dy\;,$$ Let $\displaystyle y = -\sec \phi\;,$ Then $\displaystyle dy = -\sec \phi\cdot \tan \phi d \phi$ and changing Limit

We get $$\displaystyle I = \int_{\frac{\pi}{4}}^{\frac{\pi}{3}}\frac{-\sec \phi\cdot \tan \phi}{-\sec \phi\cdot \tan \phi} d\phi = \left[\phi\right]_{\frac{\pi}{4}}^{\frac{\pi}{3}} = \left(\frac{\pi}{4}-\frac{\pi}{3}\right) = \frac{\pi}{12}$$

$\bf{Another\; way::}$ Given $$\displaystyle I = \int_{-\sqrt{2}}^{-2}\frac{1}{y\sqrt{y^2-1}}dy\;,$$ Now Put $\displaystyle y = -\frac{1}{t}\;,$ Then $\displaystyle dy = \frac{1}{t^2}dt$ and Changing Limit, We get

$$\displaystyle I = -\int_{\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}}^{\frac{1}{2}}\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-t^2}}dt = -\left[\sin^{-1}(t)\right]_{\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}}^{\frac{1}{2}} = -\left[\sin^{-1}\left(
\frac{1}{2}\right)-\sin^{-1}\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\right)\right]$$

So we get $$\displaystyle I = -\left[\sin^{-1}\left(
\sin \frac{\pi}{6}\right)-\sin^{-1}\left(\sin \frac{\pi}{4}\right)\right] = -\left[\frac{\pi}{6}-\frac{\pi}{4}\right] = \frac{\pi}{12}.$$

$(2)\;\;$ Let $$\displaystyle I = \int_{-\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}}^{0}\frac{1}{1+z^2}dz$$

Put $z=\tan \phi$ and $dz = \sec^2 \phi$ and Changing Limit, We get

$$\displaystyle I = \int_{-\frac{\pi}{6}}^{0}\frac{\sec^2 \phi}{\sec^2 \phi}d\phi = \left[\phi\right]_{-\frac{\pi}{6}}^{0} = \left[0-\left(-\frac{\pi}{6}\right)\right] = \frac{\pi}{6}$$

$(3)\;\;$ Let $$\displaystyle I = \int_{\frac{1}{2}}^{-\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}}\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}dx$$

Put $x=\sin \phi\;,$ Then $dx = \cos \phi d\phi$ and Changing Limit, We get

$$\displaystyle I = \int_{\frac{\pi}{6}}^{\frac{3\pi}{4}}\frac{\cos \phi}{\cos \phi}d\phi = \left[\phi\right]_{\frac{\pi}{6}}^{\frac{3\pi}{4}} = \left(\frac{3\pi}{4}-\frac{\pi}{6}\right) = \frac{7\pi}{12}.$$

Comment: how did you find the new values for the integral endpoints?

Comment: and thank you for your help.

Comment: When $y=-\sqrt{2}\;,$ Then $\displaystyle -\sqrt{2} = -\sec\phi\Rightarrow \sec\phi = \sqrt{2}\Rightarrow \cos \phi = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$. So $\displaystyle \phi = \frac{\pi}{4}$ , Similarly for upper bond.